# npm run build cannot access in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I want to test my react/ node.js web app with a production build. I already run `npm run build` at the app directory and created build folder.

I was unable to run the application using localhost:8080 (server port).

Are there any ways to double check if the application is actually running in that port or access production-ready application?

PS. I used serve to host the application but it posts error 404: The requested path could not be found

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you ran build, you are just "compiling" your app, not serving it. You need to run something like `npm run serve`

Comment: Use Express and create a path to serve the local files.

Comment: According to official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started), you need to run `npm start`. This works if you setup your enviroment correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Every SPA application has its own package.json file. Inside you have to see the script section:
[image]

Normally after you run nm run build you have a compiled version of your code.
At this point, you have a see the `dist` folder.

After this, you can either run `npm run start` and you have to see
[image]

(this option is not suitable for SSR frameworks like NUXT or NEXT)
or if you don't have that option install an npm package that renders your compiled code by doing the following:

1. `npm install -g serve`
2. `serve -s build`
   and you have to see
   [image]